# Append node to EMF datamodel instance XML

Tags: xml, eclipse, dom, xmlnode, emf

I created a datamodel with the Eclipse Modeling Framework. Here is an instance of the datamodel in form of a XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model2:Container xmlns:model2="http://model2/1.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmi:version="2.0">
  <containsRuleElementAssociation src1="//@containsRuleElement.0" target1="//@containsRuleElement.1"/>
  <containsRuleElement name="Sergei" type="//@containsRuleElemntType.0"/>
  <containsRuleElement name="VW Polo" type="//@containsRuleElemntType.1"/>
  <containsRuleElemntType name="Person"/>
  <containsRuleElemntType name="Car"/>
  <containsRuleElementAssociationType name="drives" src="//@containsRuleElemntType.0"
target="//@containsRuleElemntType.1"/>
</model2:Container>
```

I want to dynamically append references of the type `containsRuleElement` with user input data. I'm using a DOM parser to read the xml but I dont know how to append a node of the type `containsRuleElement` type. The Node `containsRuleElement` is not of the node type `Element` because it lacks the tags. Does anybody know how to append such a node? Can I use DOM for this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind the question. I'm now using the EMF resource to create the references and add them directly. It seems to work.